# How to show IDs from mysql table as thier values from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I have two mysql tables :
1- cases ( contains many columns) one of them is ( casetype) 
2- types ( contains 2 columns ) :
   casetypeID , casetypename

casetype saved in cases table as ID .

when I want to show it appears as Number .

I need to Join ID for casetypeID to show casetype as name not number .

Thanks

````
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "data");
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
$query = "SELECT casetype, count(*) as number FROM cases GROUP BY casetype";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  

 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html dir=rtl>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <head>  
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
           function drawChart()  
           {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                          ['casetype', 'Number'],  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo "['".$row["casetype"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";  

                          }  
                          ?>  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `types`.casetypeName, count(*) as number FROM cases
inner join `types` on `types`.casetypeID = cases.casetype
GROUP BY cases.casetype
```

This query will join your 2 tables on casetypeID and casetype and will select the casetypeName from the types table.